# LogQL - label_format conditionally format a label

Tags: grafana-loki

I have a log stream from where I am extracting a set of fields to be set as either labels or metric values. The stream is not in a standard format so I am extracting the fields with regexp pipeline command, as below.

```
(...)
 | regexp "(?P<api>\\w+)\\sAPI"
 | regexp "\\[performed\\.(?P<action>\\w+)"
 | regexp "duration\\s\\[(?P<duration_ms>\\d+)"
 | regexp "response \\[(?P<response>.*?)\\]"
```

The problem is that the `api` captured field, on some interaction, is not being populated, and I wanted to update those cases so that a default value was set - For presentation purposes.

I've tried using the native LogLQ's [contains](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#contains) and [hasPrefix](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#hasprefix-and-hassuffix) template commands as the documentation suggests they can be used with `if else` blocks. The documentation is not clear on how to build those blocks inside the `label_format` or the `line_format` pipeline commands. But depending on the approach it either returns a format error or does not do anything.

An working example would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Note: Tried to tag this as a LogQL topic but not enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Any luck on this issue? I would also be interested.

Comment: The workaround I implemented was to do this on a later processing phase. I implemented the logic after the aggregation through a label_replace function. It allowed a regex replacement. I am not fully happy with the workaround.
I will try your approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With @AnthonyA's reply I was able to, after extracting a field, modify its value using the `label_format` template function.

```
 (..)
 | regexp "response \\[(?P<response>.*?)\\]"
 (..)
 | label_format api=`{{ if hasPrefix "Error" .response }}ERROR{{else}}{{.response}}{{end}}`
 (..)
```

This way the field's value is replaced by `ERROR` if it starts with "Error" and keeping its original value otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have gotten something working with `line_format`:

```
{environment=~"$environment",level=~"$level"} | json | line_format "{{ if hasSuffix `Exception` .thrown_name  }} Exception occurred! {{end}} {{.message}}" |~ "(?i)$grep"
```

The documentation for back ticks was difficult to find, and the order for method arguments is also a bit different. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With your reply I was able to figure out how to make this work the way I need. See below my answer